# Show 404 custom page without redirecting to it

Tags: apache, http-status-code-404

I want to display my 404 custom page without redirecting to it (so that the user sees what he wrote in the navigator's bar instead of seeing https://abadroch.fr/docs/404/). My researchs bring me to problems which concerns PHP but I'm just using localized-error-pages.conf (is it wrong ?) which is pretty similar to a .htaccess

```
# Customizable error responses come in three flavors:
# 1) plain text
# 2) local redirects
# 3) external redirects
#
# Some examples:
#ErrorDocument 500 "The server made a boo boo."
#ErrorDocument 404 /missing.html
#ErrorDocument 404 "/cgi-bin/missing_handler.pl"
#ErrorDocument 402 http://www.example.com/subscription_info.html
#
ErrorDocument 404 https://abadroch.fr/docs/404/index.html
```

(I used a URL because the path didn't worked)

```
However I've tested a thing concerning php (doesn't work of course)
# Customizable error responses come in three flavors:
# 1) plain text
# 2) local redirects
# 3) external redirects
#
# Some examples:
#ErrorDocument 500 "The server made a boo boo."
#ErrorDocument 404 /missing.html
#ErrorDocument 404 "/cgi-bin/missing_handler.pl"
#ErrorDocument 402 http://www.example.com/subscription_info.html
#
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /var/wwww/docs/404/index.html [L]
```

(Before editing, there was already some RewriteCond/RewriteRule so there is no need to put a RewriteEngine on)

Thanks for your help !
(Sorry for my bad english I'm a 16yo french)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

I had to move my 404 html file to the path /var/www (important) and add to the file /etc/apache2/sites-available/default.conf

```
Redirect 404 /404.html
```

I also changed the localized-error-pages.conf :

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```